# $_post not working on upload form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, upload

I have this upload form:

```
        <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <b>Select your image:</b><br><input type="file" name="userfile" id="file" size="90%" /><br>
            (Max size: 10mb)<br>
            <b>Browseable:</b><br><input type="radio" name="browse" id="browse" value="1" /> Yes <input type="radio" name="browse" id="browse" value="0" /> No<br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" size="100" />
        </form>
```

And this PHP code:

```
    <?PHP
    $maxsize = 10485760; // Max File Size IN BYtes
    $accepted = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg','JPEG', 'gif', 'ico', 'tif', 'bmp', 'PNG');
    $length = 10;
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        preg_match('/\.([a-zA-Z]+?)$/', $_FILES['userfile']['name'], $matches);

        if(in_array(strtolower($matches[1]), $accepted)) {

            if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] <= $maxsize) {

                $newname = md5_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']).'.'.$matches[1];

                $browse = $_POST["browse"];

                if ($browse = "1") {
                $filedir = 'img';
                } else {
                $filedir = 'noimg';
                }

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $filedir.'/'.$newname);

                header("Location: index.php?p=uploaded&img=$newname");
            } else 
                header("Location: index.php?p=error&num=2");
        } else
        header("Location: index.php?p=error&num=1");
    }
    ?>
```

The portion after $_POST["browse"] is not working. The purpose of this script is to put images in a folder that is either public, or private after upload. I am also curious to whether or not this upload script is secure.

Comment: [Megabyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) = "MB", not "mb".

Comment: Try print out $browse and see what you are getting

Answer (score 1):

You have assignemt operator (`=`) instead of comparision (`==` or `===`)

```
if ($browse == "1") {  // or $browse === 1 or $browse == 1
    $filedir = 'img';
} else {
    $filedir = 'noimg';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming  by `The portion after $_POST["browse"] is not working.` means that the true block is always firing?  If so, then change `if ($browse = "1")` to `if ($browse == "1")`.  Your `if` statement is checking if `$browse` can be assigned the value of 1, not if it equals 1.

Comment: That was my problem, I overlooked that. I was thinking there was a larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($browse = "1") {
```

You are assigning 1 to $browse... >> "==" !

Then do:

```
$res = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $filedir.'/'.$newname);
var_dump($res);
die;
```

To see what's happening :)